# How can I get crypto keys via SL api as in portal?

Tags: python, rest, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I'm trying to get the cryptographic keys just like portal, but I can't make my mask work, can someone tell me what's wrong with the following request, btw I am using the following url

https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/softlayer_security_certificate_request/getsslcertificaterequests

and jic python api client is used and also rest requests can work for me to get the socket layers.

```
mask = "mask[accountId, certificateSigningRequest, certificateAuthorityName, id]

response = client['SoftLayer_Security_Certificate_Request'].getsslcertificaterequests()
```

I also want to find how to search the virtual ips associated to the certificates but I don't find what api method does what i need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code will retrieve only one of the certificates and not the stored security certificates, in order to make your mask work you need to add close the string with **"** double quote, and the method you are calling should be **getSslCertificateRequests**, see below:

```
accountId = 202768 #change this value
mask = "mask[accountId, certificateSigningRequest, certificateAuthorityName, id]"
response = client['SoftLayer_Security_Certificate_Request'].getSslCertificateRequests(accountId)
```

Currently the portal use **SoftLayer_Account::getSecurityCertificate** to retrieve the stored security certificates including SSL, use the following Python script:

```
import SoftLayer
from pprint import pprint as pp

USERNAME = 'set-me'
# Endpoint url that contains all the Api Services.   
API_KEY = 'set-me'
# Generate one for you or your users, or view yours at 
https://control.softlayer.com/account/users


client = SoftLayer.create_client_from_env(username=USERNAME,
                                      api_key=API_KEY)

accountService = client['SoftLayer_Account']

try:
""""
getSecurityCertificates() retrieves stored security certificates (ie. SSL)
"""""
result = accountService.getSecurityCertificates()
pp(result)

except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
""""
If there was an error returned from the SoftLayer API then bomb out with the
error message.
"""""
print("Unable to retrieve the Account's stored security certificates (i.e. SSL) . %s %s " % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))
```

To find the virtual ip addresses associated you should use the method getAdcLoadBalancers and send the *id* value obtained in the previous method, try this Rest request.

```
https://[username]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Account/getAdcLoadBalancers?objectFilter={"adcLoadBalancers":{"securityCertificateId":{"operation":[id]}}}
```

Remember to change the **username** and **apiKey** for valid credentials, and the **id** mentioned above to retrieve the associated load balancer ip addresses.

Comment: Thanks that worked really well, but I still have troubles trying to find the documentation of service method getAdcLoadBalancers and its datataype. Is there any problem with it, as it seems not to be included or I am searching wrong.